# Background worker querying database multiple times while reporting

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task, backgroundworker

Ok so I am developing a system for a catering company, the system connects to a database. I have a splash screen that is a circular loading bar and I get it to update fine from my Background worker. I am planning on building and querying tables before my menu screen is displayed, I have added a background worker to carry out these queries.

```
Bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(setQueries);
   Bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

...

```
private void setQueries(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
//begin queries
}
```

Can someone show me a better way to do so or give me some reasoning on another way if there is a better please ??
My queries are held in a separate class and are stored in methods, each ran in the DoWork event handler.. I am just wondering if this is the best way to schedule these tasks and run them or is there a better way that is more elegant. I am a beginner with multi threading and have only used it once for one large task rather than small tasks like queries and populating tables. 
Is it better to create 'Tasks' or to take another approach?
Any advice or help will be appreciated, thank you

EDIT: this is for a piece of coursework

Comment: _"Is it better to create 'Tasks'"_ If by "Tasks" you mean `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` - then that would be the more "state-of-the-art" approach (I am talking about Taskbased Async Pattern / async await Task). The thing is: What is your definition of "better"? If Backgroundworkers are familiar to you and readable and maintainable, then they might be better _for you_. Using them is not "wrong" at the end of the day.

Comment: Is it wrong to use them with multiple methods in the DoWork? I would like to use whatever is most appropriate, is tasks what you would recommend

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd recommend using the Taskbased Async Pattern, yes. But there are pitfalls. If you have a deadline to keep and you are familiar with BGW and things *work*, I wouldn't say it's wrong to use them (even with several db operations in one DoWork). But this is pretty opinionated, I am afraid - hence not an answer. Also, I don't consider myself too much of a secure source for advice on that matter. I don't know your project, your level of knowledge ... There may be arguments against it I haven't thought of, yet.

Comment: It's actually for a piece of school coursework, although it's very large and I'm going for full marks and background workers only is beyond our specification, it's more for myself, I will use BGW in this case

Comment: _"for a piece of school coursework"_ It is always well-received on SO if you state that in the question. It can make a difference for an answer if code is really for "prodiction" or more "academic".